# View password protected office files(word, excel, etc) online

Tags: ms-office, password-protection

Trying to find a solution to view password protected office files(word, excel, etc) online in the browser.

Example:

the **backend stored** a word file that had been **password** protected.

User from the **browser** side can view the word file **directly** in the browser by **typing** in the password in a browser pop up box

the **backend never has to know the password in any way**.

#### Tried searching for a solution, did not find any applicable.

https://blog.groupdocs.com/merger/lock-unlock-word-documents-with-password-in-java/  This seems like it could work, but it has the **risk of delivering a word file that had its password protection removed to the front end**.

As of 2023, is this doable on the web?

Comment: You need to implement the required functionality on the server.